# How to set DataGridView textbox column to multi-line?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

How to let "`DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`" in `DataGridView` **supports Multiline property**?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by setting the `WrapMode` of the `DefaultCellStyle` of your `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` to `true`.

Comment: you also need to set `dataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;` see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706454/c-multiline-text-in-datagridview-control)

Comment: Remember that if you use custom Cell Styles in your table, you'll need to specify the WrapMode for each one you want wrapping, as new Styles default it to false.

Answer (score 33):

I have found that there are two things that you need to do, both in the designer, to make a text cell show multiple lines. As **Tim S. Van Haren** mentioned, you need to set `WrapMode` of the `DefaultCellStyle` of your `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` to `true`. And although that does make the text wrap, it doesn't make the row expand to show anything beyond the first line. In addition to `WrapMode`, the `AutoSizeRowsMode` of the `DataGridView` must be set to the appropriate `DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode` enumeration value. A value such as `DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells` allows the cell to expand vertically and show the entire wrapped text.

Comment: For reference, `AutoSizeRowsMode` is a property of the `DataGridView`, and needs to be set to something like `DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells`

Comment: As @BenScott has stated, [`DataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autosizerowsmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not a boolean value and must be assigned the appropriate `DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode` enumeration value. I will edit the answer to reflect this.

Comment: I also set the AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode  to have True to get it to work.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from setting `WrapMode` of the `DefaultCellStyle`, you can do the following:

1. You need to catch GridView's `EditingControlShowing` Event
2. Cast `Control` property on the EventArgs to the type you want (i.e. textbox, checkbox, or button)
3. Using that casted type, change the `Multiline` property like below:

```cs
private void MyGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox TB = (TextBox)e.Control;
    TB.Multiline = true;            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int multilineht = 0;
    private void CustGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        multilineht = CustGridView.Rows[CustGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Height;
        CustGridView.AutoResizeRow(CustGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex, DataGridViewAutoSizeRowMode.AllCells);
    }

    private void CustGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        CustGridView.Rows[CustGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Height = multilineht;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to set Multiline property just for one column of your `DataGridView`
you can do

```
dataGridView.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```

Comment: Question was answered 11 years ago, do you really think your answer is better than accepted one?

Comment: @IgorGoyda Yes as it seems there is no answer for creator question "how to make Multiline property for a column". This is what I was searching for and did not find answer here. He did not asked how to make it for every column and all the answers lead to it. Also many answers were made 3 years ago so I wonder why are you so rude towards me.

Comment: I guess you missed the accepted answer, please, read it carefully. As for me, I don't see a difference between yours and accepted.

Comment: I guess I missed the accepted answer, too - specifically the "DefaultCellStyle" component. This plainly lists example code that works, which in this case, helped me get past my stumbling block, so +1 for that, even 11+ years after the original poster.