# C#: multiline text in DataGridView control

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, c#-2.0

Is it possible for the DataGridView control to display multiline text in a cell?

I am using Visual Studio 2005 and C#.

Comment: Some what similar post, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559867/how-to-set-datagridview-textbox-column-to-multi-line.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You should set `DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode` property of column to `DataGridViewTriState.True`. After that text in cells will be displayed correctly.

Example (`DataGridView` with one column):

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("test" + Environment.NewLine + "test");
```

(`Environment.NewLine` = `\r\n` in Windows)

Comment: This may not be enough. You should also set the row heights. Or dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;

Comment: Excellent Dude. You saved my time . Thumps up.

Answer (score 21):

```
dgv.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
dgv.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to active the multiline text in `DataGridView` control then `WrapMode` should be true

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You can change open datagridview property directly

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got it to work this way (in addition to setting both AutoSizeRowsMode to AllCells and AutoSizeColumnsMode to AllCells):

```
dgvTwinReverb.Columns[PEANUT_GALLERY_COLUMN].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
dgvTwinReverb.Columns[PEANUT_GALLERY_COLUMN].MinimumWidth = PEANUT_GALLERY_COLUMN_DESIRED_WIDTH;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dgv.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
dgv.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1- Datagridview > properties > DataGridViewCellStyle > WrapMode=True
2 -Datagridview > properties > DataGridViewCellStyle > AutoRowSizeMode=AllCells
3- Datagridview > properties > Cloumn >(cloumn selected which you want to multiline)
      DefaultCellStyle > Alingment=NotSet and WrapMode=NotSet
```