# Multiline Textbox Column in DataGridView

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I want to have a multiline textbox to display data in a DataGridView. [I found a solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706454/c-multiline-text-in-datagridview-control) but that is not working for me. Here is my code that I am trying to fix the problem with:

myDataGridView.Columns["Column1"].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;

I noticed that I can scroll inside of the textboxes, but their height is not correct so I cannot see all of the data at once. I want their height to be such that I can see all of their content at once.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: So multi-line works? You just need to see it all at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. When I set "AutoSizeRowsMode" to "AllCells" that caused the row height to default to what I wanted.