# How can I display multi line text from access database into DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

this is my Access database

[image]

as you see in Blood Group Row I have a multiline in testUnit Column A+, A-, O+, O-, etc...

my problem is below

[image]

Why dataGridView display these lines text between divs ?
I set `Wrap-text true`
but it doesn't solve my problem ..
the expected output in datagridview

- A+
- A-
- O+
- O-

( without div tag )

### **I SOLVED THIS QUESTION AFTER CHANGE SOME THING IN DATABASE**

DATATYPE of field (field used to store many lines in) SHOULD BE `Long Text` and make the TextFormat plain text as show below
[image]

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706454/c-multiline-text-in-datagridview-control ?

Comment: @CaiusJard i already see this question but it doesnt solve my problem

Comment: Show how you get data into the datagridview

Comment: I got this <div>A+</div>

<div>A-</div>

<div>O+</div>

<div>O-</div>

<div>&nbsp;</div> and I put a screenshot in my post

Comment: @OlivierRogier unfortunately didnt solved my question.. I set ```default cell style > wrapmode true``` and nothing effected

Comment: @Aiman, instead of editing question, could have written an answer and mark it accepted.

Comment: I VTC this question because it was effectively caused by a typo. In future, do not edit your question to include an answer; post your own answer. You're allowed to answer your own questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this in your DataBase

[image]

And Add this query to display data from MS-Access into dataGridView without (`<div>`) annoying tag

```
 
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("your connection string");
        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

     private void getDataBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Table]", con);
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

When rebinding your columns, use Eval("testUnit") instead of bind.
I remember this for you, i hope this is useful for you...