# How do I ensure a textbox column in a DataGridView shows in multiline / wordwrap mode?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewtextboxcell

How do I show textbox column of a datagridview in multiline format using vb.net?

Comment: possible duplicate from:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559867/how-to-set-datagridview-textbox-column-to-multi-line

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `WrapMode` property of the `DefaultCellStyle` property of your `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`.

See here for details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.wrapmode.aspx