# How to set the DataGridViewCell to automatically word wrap?

Tags: c#, winforms

The code below which I found on MSN did not worked to automatically word-wrap a cell:

```
dataGridView.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;

dataGridView.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```

Any more answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set DataGridView textbox column to multi-line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559867/how-to-set-datagridview-textbox-column-to-multi-line)

Comment: I found AutoSizeMode 
 = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill worked better for me

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You also need to set `DataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells` (along with what you have done) for word-wrap to work.

Answer (score 13):

This may help someone.

If you need target specific columns use the below as what is int he question will not work, as items is not available in c# 4.5

```
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
dataGridView1.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
dataGridView1.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```

Answer (score 5):

Just Add This Lines in  **form_Load**  Method

```
this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```

Answer (score 2):

just include the second line in code..... like in my code ... it is working perfectly

```
da.Fill(dtusers);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dtusers;
// dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also make it, in this way

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn comments = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
{
    comments.Name = "comments";
    comments.HeaderText = "Comments";
    comments.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
    comments.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
    this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(comments);
}
```