# Increase datagridview row size automatically with wrapmode

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have read so many article to do my task. I want to use wrapmode to increase the height of the cell when the content reaches the cell width. The text want to display in a new line in that cell only.
So many articles refer me to set

```
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode =DataGridViewTriState.True;
dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells
```

I have set these two properties to may datagridview.. Still the text is not wrapping in the cell. Am I missing anything??

Comment: Maybe you need to set it to [`DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6326852/570150)

Comment: @V4Vendetta: Sorry I have tried that too..

Comment: DataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode...should be DataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode...

Comment: Check this out too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847993/how-to-set-the-datagridviewcell-to-automatically-word-wrap

Comment: @V4Vendetta: Your suggestion is for auto side column width. I need autosize column height.. thank you