# Change datagrid view cell to multiline if its content gets more than a specific width

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, cell

I want to show database data in a grid view in C# by this code  :

```
 public void Selectalbums()
        {
            string QuerySelect = "select * from albums_tbl ";
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(QuerySelect, cn );
            SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
        }
```

now when I want to show a big string in a cell , it does not show compeletely ! 
how can I do this : 
[image]

I set a maximum width for a column's cells (for exampele 250 px)and if the string is bigger than 250 px it will be shown in multiline mode ! 
I searched for it in stackoverflow and other sites but I did note find a solution

the width is Constante but when the stirring getting bigger this cell will be multiline

I'm using. NET Framework 3.5

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are setting a column's maximum width. But if that maximum width is equivalent to the column's actual width, then the answer is simply:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[columnIndex].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
dataGridView1.AutoResizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
```

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1706581/3773066), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4848027/3773066), and [numerous other places](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=datagridview%20individual%20cell%20multiline).

If they are not equivalent then you could have the following situations:

1. Cell value fits within the cell width.

   - Display normally.
2. Cell value is longer than the cell width but shorter than max width.

   - Display with ellipses.
3. Cell value is longer than the cell width and the max width.

   - Display as a multiline/wrapped cell.

To handle it is pretty similar but on a cell by cell basis instead of the whole column. Below is an example:

```
private int column0MaxWidth = 100;
this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 55;
this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;

// For contrast - column 1 contains the same data but is autosized.
this.dataGridView1.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;

// On cell formatting, change a cell to single-lined or multilined.
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
  DataGridViewTextBoxCell cell = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewTextBoxCell;

  if (cell != null && e.ColumnIndex == 0)
  {
    cell.Style.WrapMode = TextRenderer.MeasureText(cell.Value.ToString(), cell.Style.Font).Width > column0MaxWidth ? DataGridViewTriState.True : DataGridViewTriState.NotSet;
  }
}
```

[image: Wrapped vs unwrapped cell]

This could easily be adapted for multiple columns depending how you set each column's max width.