# Why I cannot wrap a text into DataGridView cell in C#?

Tags: c#

I am using windows forms C#.

I am trying to wrap a text into a `datagridview` cell but the text does not get wrapped.

I enabled the wrap mode and I set the `datagridview` `Rows` to `autoSize` but the wraping still did not work

```
DataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = True;

dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = True;
```

It works only if I add "\n" somewhere in the text for example:

```
dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value = "123456" +"\n" + "ABCDE";
```

But as shown in the screenshot it does not wrap if I enter this text into the cell with no "\n" :

```
dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value = "123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMN"
```

[image: screenshot]

Anyone knows what is wrong or how can I enable cell wrapping without using `\n`? please help . Thank you

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847993/how-to-set-the-datagridviewcell-to-automatically-word-wrap

Comment: @ vcsjones . I already see this question and did not work. I sat  dataGridView1.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells and it did not wrap . column1 pushed another column out of the DGV but no wrap. any idea?

Comment: I think it will wrap the next word...but in your case it is big one word...Split that word by putting space...

Comment: @Kate, Try DataGridView.Column[1].ItemStyle-Wrap  = 'False' Or 'True' .