# How to set rows' height to automatically resize so contents fit

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm working on DataGridView and was wondering if there's a property that automatically makes cells bigger if the content requires it.

So far I have, at the end of the DataGridViewBindingComplete handler:

```
dataGridView1.AutoResizeRows(DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells);
```

But unfortunately, that didn't do the trick.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void dgv1BindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.AutoResizeRows(DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells);
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // [...] set up datasource: orders

        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = orders;

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn idCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        idCol.DataPropertyName = "id";
        idCol.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCellsExceptHeader;
        idCol.HeaderText = "#";
        idCol.DisplayIndex = 0;

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn placedCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        placedCol.DataPropertyName = "placed";
        placedCol.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCellsExceptHeader;
        placedCol.HeaderText = "Time Placed";
        placedCol.DisplayIndex = 1;

        // [...] more of these columns

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(idCol);
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(placedCol);
        // [...] adding the rest of the columns

        dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += dgv1BindingComplete;
    }
}
```

With the following result:

[image: Orders description is on one line. Image cell is not enlarged.]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer was hidden in another Stackoverflow question: [How to set DataGridView textbox column to multi-line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559867/how-to-set-datagridview-textbox-column-to-multi-line)

Setting the DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode to TriState.True did the trick.

Answer (score 6):

```
datagridview1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
datagridview1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCellsExceptHeaders
```

Comment: This is clear and concise answer. In my case I had increased the font size and the row height didn't change. Somehow I missed the property in the Layout section.

Answer (score 1):

Set property ***AutoSizeColumnMode*** of *datagridview* to  ***AllCells*** and check it.

Comment: I tried that, but for some reason the cells still don't wrap or adjust their height.

Comment: Had to start over because I navigated the Designer into a dead end. Will post code when I encounter the problem again, which should be soon.

Comment: I guess you meant AutoSizeRowsMode