# Multiple lines in a DataGridView cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Using `C#` `Windows Forms`;

I have a `DataGridView` with a number of cells. I would like to show digits (from 1-9) in the cell. The digits should be placed under each other in a `3x3` format.

I looked around, and only ended up with a rather complex custom implementation of a `richtextbox` cell.

Is there a way I can draw a `custom rectangle` and then implement this as `backgroundimage` of the cell or something? The cell need to be redrawn several times. So I can't just call the `paint` event I guess.

*Note:* The cell must not be edited by the user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set DataGridView textbox column to multi-line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559867/how-to-set-datagridview-textbox-column-to-multi-line)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I don't know if this will satisfy you, but you can use `Environment.NewLine` to create simple line break inside cell.

Example:

```
string nl = Environment.NewLine; // new line variable
string data = "1 2 3" + nl + "4 5 6" + nl + "7 8 9";
```

Added later:

As [Adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920798/adrian) said in comments - you will need to:

1. Set the WrapMode for the `DataGridViewColumn` to `DataGridViewTriState.True`
2. Make sure you set a height for the row, or set the DataGridView's `AutoSizeRowsMode` to `DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells`

If you don't want to edit that column - you can set `DataGridView.Column.ReadOnly` property to `true`.

Update:
It took me a while to find this property with the above information. In VS C# 2017 the WrapMode property is located in the datagridview `DefaultCellStyle` dialog.

Comment: already did this. Problem is that cell is a textbox not rich textbox. So everything is situated on 1 line, regardless of the given string :/

Comment: In addition to this you need to set the `WrapMode` for the `DataGridViewColumn` to `DataGridViewTriState.True` and make sure you set a height for the row, or set the `DataGridView`'s `AutoSizeRowsMode` to `DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells`

Comment: @user1933169 i added information how to disable edit on column. If you need more details - just ask in comments.

Answer (score 4):

as a supplement:

```
dataGridView.Columns[x].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
dataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
```

x  = Column-Index

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on GridView >> properties>>DefaultCellStyle>>Wrapmode=True

Comment: It works. as a supplement: dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;