# DataGridView DefaultCellStyle Preventing BackColor Changes

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, backcolor

What I am doing is comparing two datatables checking for changes.  If a table cell value changes I mark the corresponding DataGridView cell by changing its BackColor property.  This has worked perfectly until I needed to set the DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True and DataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells.  I needed to do this so I could have text go to a new line inside of a cell.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514352/multiple-lines-in-a-datagridview-cell) is a StackOverflow answer which explains this. So after setting a DefaultCellStyle I was unable to change the BackColor.  However I have a Validator class which gets a DataGridViewCell passed in and validates the value. If the text in the cell is not valid or in correct format the Style.BackColor gets changed...THIS WORKS! My question is why can my Validator class change the BackColor but I can't directly from the form?  Here is a simplified example of what I am doing and what I am experiencing:

```
    private void initDataGridView()
    {
        DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
        DataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
        DataGridView.MultiSelect = false;
        DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        DataGridView.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        DataGridView.RowHeadersVisible = false;

        // ADD EVENT HANDLERS
        DataGridView.CellEndEdit += DataGridView_CellEndEdit;
    }

    private void compareTables()
    {
        string dataTableCell;
        string dataTableMirrorCell;

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dataTable.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
        {
            for (int colIndex = 2; colIndex < dataTable.Columns.Count; colIndex++)
            {
                // initialize cell values to compare
                dataTableCell = dataTable.Rows[rowIndex].Field<string>(colIndex);
                dataTableMirrorCell = dataTableMirror.Rows[rowIndex].Field<string>(colIndex);

                // now compare cell values
                if (dataTableCell != dataTableMirrorCell)
                {
                    if (dataTableCell== null
                        || dataTableCell== string.Empty)
                    {
                        dataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        dataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].Tag = "Delete";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (dataTableMirrorCell == null
                            || dataTableMirrorCell == string.Empty)
                        {
                            dataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Orange;
                            dataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].Tag = "Add";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                            dataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].Tag = "Change";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
        Validator validator = new Validator(this);

        if (e.ColumnIndex != dgv.Columns["Name"].Index)
        {
            DataGridViewCell cell = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

            // Check the value for valid format
            validator.validateCell(cell, ValidationType.Numeric);               
        }
    }
```

Here is the Validator.validateCell method:

```
    public void validateCell(DataGridViewCell cell, String type)
    {
        // NUMERIC
        if (type.ToLower() == "numeric")
        {
            int result;
            if (!int.TryParse(cell.Value.ToString(), out result))
            {
                cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Beige;
                cell.Style.Font = new Font(this.form.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
                cell.ToolTipText = "This is a " + type + " only field.";
                cell.Tag = "invalid";
            }
            else
            {
                cell.Style.BackColor = Color.White;
                cell.Style.Font = new Font(this.form.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
                cell.ToolTipText = string.Empty;
                cell.Tag = "valid";
            }
        }
    }
```

Validator.validateCell WORKS, it changes the cell BackColor and the Font.  Can someone explain why a local method, compareTables, does not change BackColor and my validator.validateCell does?  Many thanks for helping me learn!

Answer (score 1):

I have always used:

```
dataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
```

To set or get a dataGridView background color. Not sure if that will help you look in another direction

Comment: thanks for the reply! Well, this is not really what I am trying to do.  If I use RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor it changes the color of the currently selected cell(s). What I want is to change the BackColor of any cells that have been changed

Comment: @wailmagic You may have to set the FormattingEvent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105718/datagridview-changing-cell-background-color

Comment: I have used the CellFormatting event before to format cells in a DGV.  I will experiment using CellFormatting to see if I can find a solution.  If I do I will report back and post my solution.  Thanks Luk6e