# DatagridView multi items in one Column

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out how can i send two items (Up and down inside a column) from sql server.

Here is my existing code:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(" SELECT name,Subname,Code,Price from Customers", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        AppointmentGrid.Rows.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
        {
            int n = AppointmentGrid.Rows.Add();

            AppointmentGrid.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item[0].ToString();
            AppointmentGrid.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item[1].ToString();
            AppointmentGrid.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item[2].ToString();
            AppointmentGrid.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item[3].ToString();
          }
```

I need 'Name' and 'Subname' to be inside one column in my datagridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need 'Name' and 'Subname' to be inside one column in my datagridview.

You can use 2 approaches to do that.

**First Approach**

When you get data from the database, concatenate the 2 columns:

```
SELECT name + ' ' + Subname as NameAndSubname, Code, Price from Customers
```

**Second Approach**

Do the concatenation on the application side:

```
AppointmentGrid.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = 
    item[0].ToString() + " " + item[1].ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you your code works but what if i want to add new line??This code it adds items side by side

Comment: @Dss Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514352/multiple-lines-in-a-datagridview-cell) for how to do that.

Comment: Thank you Solved with DeafaultCellStyle Wraped and autosizerowmode -AllCells