# Uncorrect showing information in dataGridView

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, datagridview, line

I have a C# .NEW Framework app, that works with JSON files. Here method that getting data from JSON file:

```
        public virtual Hashtable Load()
        {
            try
            {
                var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(FileName);

                var userProblems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Hashtable>(jsonString);
                return userProblems;
            }
            catch { return null; }
        }
```

I also have a dataGridView into which I output data using this code:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Show all user problems in dataGridView.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="date">date of concrete problem</param>
        /// <param name="rowIndex">row index in dataGridView</param>
        private void ShowProblems(KeyValuePair<string, JToken> date, ref short rowIndex)
        {

            var userProblems = (JObject)date.Value;
            //TODO: creating new field for problem.
            _problemsList.Rows.Add(date.Key);

            //depending of every problem status, give to check box needed value.
            if (userProblems["issolved"].ToString() == "False")
                _problemsList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].Value = false;
            else
                _problemsList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].Value = true;

            _problemsList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value = userProblems["text"].ToString();

            rowIndex++;
        }
```

Problem in that, that in JSON file I have this: [image: ![enter image description here]

Line break - "\n". But in dataGridView I have this:[image]

I tried to use Environment.NewLine property like this:

```
 _problemsList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value = userProblems["text"] + Environment.NewLine + "some text";
```

But I have this:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution: [Multiple lines in a DataGridView cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514352/multiple-lines-in-a-datagridview-cell/16514393)

If link will be not actual:

1. we must go to the "Edit Columns" panel.
2. There we need choose needed column of dataGridView.
3. Go to default cell style.
4. and there we need change Wrap mode to the true value.