# Parsing new line from a string in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, datagridview

I have a string with emojis and new lines in it. I am using Regex to remove the emoji.

```
string text = "S H A V A . Est 2015\nBandung\nLine: @ubm5921j\nBbm: 7D2E6310\nFAST ORDER\ud83d\udc47\ud83c\udffe\ud83d\udc47\ud83c\udffe";
string result = Regex.Replace(text, @"\p{Cs}", "");
```

That works fine until I want to add the string in my dataGridView, using this line:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("TestData", "TestData", "TestData", result);
```

For some reason, it skips the '\n' in the result string and outputs the whole string in one line. How can I add the string with new lines in the dataGrid?

Comment: Try `Environment.NewLine();` and increase height of the grid row.

Comment: `Environment.NewLine()` returns `\r\n`.

Comment: @M.NasserJavaid The grid row is pretty big (Size: 573; 276).

Comment: @all `\n` *is* treated properly as a newline in C# strings. The `\r` is needed for *files*. Most likely the gridview isn't set to display multiline strings. By default, Textboxes, labels (and grid cells) do *not* display as multiple lines

Comment: See [How to set DataGridView textbox column to multi-line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559867/how-to-set-datagridview-textbox-column-to-multi-line)